# Cannot find module "@supercharge/strings" or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to simplify the string usage with [@supercharge/strings](https://superchargejs.com/docs/3.x/strings) but I can't run it over a TypeScript project.

If there are no types to install, can I use it anyway?

After installing with recommended command `npm i @supercharge/strings` I am getting this error:

> Unable to find module "@supercharge/strings" or its declarations of corresponding types.ts(2307)

Despite the NPM package seems to support TypeScript:
[image]

I have tried to install the declarations with `npm install -D @types/supercharge/strings` and `@types/supercharge` but they don't seem to exist.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, TS Playground is able to load the module and its definitions as expected: https://tsplay.dev/W4xpKW

Comment: @ghybs, well, I've tried with Code Sandbox and it was also able load its definitions as expected.

Comment: It was a VSCode error and it was fixed after restarting the editor.